# Adding category axis to matplotlib matshow

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 300 items belonging to several categories:

> First 84 items: Category A
>
> Next 116 items: Category B
>
> Last 100 items: Category C

There is a distance between every item, and I have created a 300x300 symmetric distance matrix from it.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10)) #to make the figure larger
plt.matshow(distances, fignum=1)
```

gives me a figure (let's call it Figure F) where x and y axis ticks are at 50,100,150,...

However, I would also like to see the category labels in that plot.

For example, the ticks on the vertical axis of Figure F can be at positions 1, 85, and 201 with corresponding category labels.

Alternatively, adding a vertical line segment to the left of Figure F  which is divided into three parts with category labels on each part would work. (of course the height of the vertical line segment should be the same as the height of Figure F)

How can I see which rows correspond to which category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said, just adding the lines:

```
plt.matshow(dist)
plt.vlines([84,200],0,299)
plt.hlines([84,200],0,299)
```

Output:

[image]